# How to fix undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following line in my Rails app:

```
@images = @product.secondary_images.split(",")
```

When @product.secondary_images has content in it, this runs fine.  However, when there is no content, I get this error:

```
undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I assign another value to @images if there is no content in it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A possible solution would be to use `try` which does return nil in case your method cannot be sent to `secondary_images`. And then use the OR-operator to assign something else.

```
@images = @product.secondary_images.try(:split, ",") || 'some other value'
```

Answer (score 7):

Or with the [safe navigation operator (&.)](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/):

```
nil&.split(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try` method

```
nil.try(:split, ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally subjective answer, but I'd probably handle it this way myself, if I wanted it all in one line:

```
@images = @product.secondary_images.nil? ? 'another value' : @product.secondary_images.split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this easier than try.

```rb
nil.to_s.split(",")
```