# undefined method `last' for nil:NilClass for youtube embed in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube, embed

I'm trying to embed a youtube video in my rails app and am following [this guide:](http://blog.41studio.com/embed-responsive-youtube-video-in-rails-4/)

I've written this helper:

```
  def embed(video)
    youtube_id = @page.video.try(:split, "=").last || 'blank'
    content_tag(:iframe, nil, src: "//www.youtube.com/embed/#{youtube_id}")
  end
```

I'm getting this error: undefined method `last' for nil:NilClass

Here's what I have in my view: pages/show.html.erb

```
    <div class="embed-container">
      <%= embed(@page.video) %>
    </div>
```

The guide seems pretty straight forward so I'm not sure why my original version wasn't working.

My original helper looked like this:

```
  def embed(video)
    youtube_id = video.split("=").last 
    content_tag(:iframe, nil, src: "//www.youtube.com/embed/#{youtube_id}")
  end
```

but it was throwing another error: **undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass**

I [went here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678473/how-to-fix-undefined-method-split-for-nilnilclass-error) and found what I thought might be a solution but it led to the new error above. I also tried adding @page.video.split instead of just video because it's the show view for a specific page but I'm not sure that make's a difference.

Any suggestions for how I can get this to work?

Comment: Your original helper is better; the problem is that `@page.video` is nil.

Comment: check what `@page.video` is returning

Comment: what is your `@page` exactly? and can you show where are you initialising it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing `@page` instance variable in your helper, but you are also sending it as an argument.

```
def embed(video)
  youtube_id = video.try(:split, "=").last || 'blank'
  content_tag(:iframe, nil, src: "//www.youtube.com/embed/#{youtube_id}")
end

<div class="embed-container">
  <%= embed(@page.video) %>
</div>
```

Having said that, the problem is that your `@page.video` is returning `nil` instead of a video URL string I guess... Make sure `@page.video` returns something.

Comment: So you were right. First I had to set the embed link code to this <%= embed(@page.video) unless @page.video == nil %> . I had also forgotten to add video to strong params. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to help. You might want to select this answer, so that the question gets marked as closed.